# Anonymous functions using interface with multiple methods?

Tags: java

What happens if `Predicate<T>` contains multiple methods?  It's my understanding if they have the same argument signature this is not allowed.

I ask because I'm considering the `Comparator<T>` interface and it has multiple methods in the interface, but with different signatures.  I look at `TreeSet<T>` constructor `TreeSet(Comparator<? super E> comparator)` and it accepts a lambda, yet I'm confused how that lambda represents `equals(Object obj)`.  Can anyone clarify this?

```
interface Predicate<T> {
    boolean test(T t);
}

public static void printPersons(
    List<Person> roster, Predicate<Person> tester) {

    for (Person p : roster) {
        if (tester.test(p)) {
            p.printPerson();
        }
    }
}

printPersons(
    roster,
    (Person p) -> p.getGender() == Person.Sex.MALE
        && p.getAge() >= 18
        && p.getAge() <= 25
);
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.8

Comment: The `Comparator` does not represent `Object#equals`, that method exists for _every_ object. Rather, `Comparator<T>` provides an `int compare(T left, T right);` abstract method (and explicitly re-states the `#equals` method). Note that you can have more than one method in a functional interface, but they must be static or defaulted. You can only have _one_ abstract method for an interface to be a _functional_ interface. The JLS link above adds an exception: public methods of `Object` are excluded (so 1:1 re-declaration of them will not count).

Comment: @Rogue https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html indicates equal and compare are both abstract so doesn’t Comparator have two abstract methods?

Comment: @notaorb hence the exception from the JLS link: public methods of `Object` are excluded from this "1 abstract method" rule. Since `boolean equals(Object other)` is defined in `Object` (and no Object method is abstract to begin with, but that's an aside), then the abstract method `boolean equals(Object other);` isn't counted: it's already implicitly covered/implemented by anything that could implement the interface, including lambdas.